# SAP FIORI Tools - Filter generated via XML UI local Annotations, require to display Clear button

Tags: annotations, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am exploring XML Annotations on WebIDE. To display filters, have added SelectedFields. I want to add reset or Clear button with Go Button. Could you please update property to add such button via annotation.

[image: UI Annotations - WebIDE Editor]

[image: Clear Button used for Filter Bar]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Bhuvenesh

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Web IDE, you can enable these buttons with the help of SAPUI5 Visual Editor i.e by creating flex changes.

Additionally, I would recommend you to explore new SAP Fiori tools on VSCode and SAP Business Application Studio https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPSE.sap-ux-fiori-tools-extension-pack

Documentation https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_FIORI_tools/Latest/en-US